# Averaging ES from the same study in a MA

Tags: meta-analysis, meta-regression

I'm completing a meta-analysis looking for an effect size for rates of forgetting for people with epilepsy vs controls.

I've already decided to separately extract effect size for the verbal and non verbal measures used. However, some studies use more than one verbal measure, or indeed split their analysis for the same measure (e.g spatial recall, descriptive recall etc).

What's the best approach for a meta-analysis and meta regression (of methodological quality and effect size)?
Can I simply add ES for spatial recall and descriptive recall etc and then divide by 2 for an average for that specific measure?
Can I get an average of two measures used within the same study for an overall ES of the study's use of that measure? Or is there a standard approach to resolving this issue?

I'm also unsure how I would even enter an average ES to MA software, as I wouldn't have a p value for that average (but I have one for each measure used)

I hope these garbled questions make an ounce of sense?! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are "ES" and "MA"?

Comment: Sorry, Effect Size and Meta Analysis

Comment: You may want to enter multi-level meta-analysis<your favourite statistical software> into your favourite search engine. What you want to do it certainly possible in R and, I assume, in Stata.

Comment: Can it be done >> Yes. Should it be done >> maybe yes... maybe no. It depends on a better understanding of your study designs, similarity of what the tests measure, etc. Also, depending on how the data is reported per study will affect what you can/ can't do. Don't mean to be so vague, but that's where we spend hours/ days understanding all these points before making a decision (preferably in the protocol stage) about what can and can't be combined. In our team we assign a methodologist, content expert and statistician to work together because the answer is often a complex one.

Answer (score 1):

Just to pull together the comments into an answer.

This would be a good example of multi-level meta-analysis which takes account of the correlation between the different outcomes within study. This is available in R and in Stata (I assume, I have never used Stata for this purpose). Exactly how to do this will also depend on what can be extracted from the primary studies.

As @abousetta stated in comment though just because you can do it does not mean you should which would depend in what the underlying scientific question of the meta-analysis was. It may be that multi-level meta-analysis does not in fact answer the question.